# Does bool query exist execution order?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to know the execution order of bool query

Does `filter` first then `must` ?

```
OST _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "term" : { "user.id" : "kimchy" }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term" : { "tags" : "production" }
      },
      "must_not" : {
        "range" : {
          "age" : { "gte" : 10, "lte" : 20 }
        }
      },
      "should" : [
        { "term" : { "tags" : "env1" } },
        { "term" : { "tags" : "deployed" } }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the term query on `user.id` should go into the `filter` array, because it's an exact match query which doesn't require scoring, hence `must` doesn't make sense. `must` should be used for free-text queries that require scoring, not exact yes/no queries which don't.

But to answer your question, yes, `filter` and `must_not` (what we call the [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html)) are executed first in order to reduce the document set to the smallest possible set, and then `must` and `should` queries (what we call the [query context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html)) are run on that document set.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-query-execution-order) on Elasticsearch official website exactly about this topic. I don't know if it still holds true since the post was made in 2017. Of course, you can read it to have the better understanding, but for a quick summary, it says

> there is no simple answer to "which query runs first"!

We also think that `filter` should be executed before queries to reduce the document set, but the blog claims that

> Everything is interleaved, regardless of whether they are queries of filters.

It is really difficult to know which queries/filters are executed first. This internal information is not exposed. There is one way which might help is to look into the [Profile API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html), as suggested by the blog.

Comment: This is an old blog article and the things have changed a little bit. I'll find my source and share it asap.

Comment: Also note that the "Conclusion" section of the linked blog article provides the answer to this question, i.e. order does not matter, no way to know in which order query/filters get executed